# ios - UIWebView Bookmark Bug with pdfs

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview, pdf-generation

I have some code that generates a pdf from text files, and adds bookmarks to various locations within said pdf using `UIGraphicsAddPDFContextDestinationAtPoint` and `UIGraphicsSetPDFContextDestinationForRect`. The `UIWebView` appears to be bugged, where clicking certain bookmarks temporarily renders other bookmarks to send the view to the top of the document. I say "temporarily" because clicking on an unaffected bookmark seems to reset all bookmarks so they point where they are supposed to.

This doesn't appear to be a coding problem, as it only occurs in `UIWebView`. When I open the pdf in iBooks, the links always work fine. However I would prefer to view the pdf in app, and the only other ways to do it that I'm aware of (`UIImageView` & `UISliderView`) would probably eliminate the bookmarks altogether. So I'm hoping there could be a way to fix `UIWebView` so this problem no longer occurs.

Any suggestions?